# How can i convert my PWM signal into digital pot?

Tags: power-supply, digital-logic, analog, switch-mode-power-supply, digital-potentiometer

I have a PWM signal and i wanted to control a high voltage by changing the Feedback resistance of that power supply using optocoupler. But its not working.

So i am thinking to convert it into analog signal, Kindly advice.

Comment: Show your schematic, please.

Comment: Normally PSU’s are remote controlled by V per mA or voltage error to Vref. So the PWM must be filtered to control slew rate of change.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is a breeze to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: @TonyM you can close the question. i got my solution. and i was able to convert my PWM signal into analog signal with ease. Thankyou everyone

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to control my optocoupler thinking to use it in Active, saturation and cut-off region by varying PWM signal. As the change in PWM was in time domain it didnt work for my application.

So i needed to change it in analog signal. In analog signal i can vary the amplitude of my signal hence can control the optocoupler in all region.

I was able to change the amplitude of my signal by varying the PWM of my signal.

The change in Amplitude was directly proportional to change in PWM.

To change the PWM signal into Analog signal i used LOW PASS FILTER.

Using 1K and 100 nF, the output shows:

[image: 1K/100nF]

I was able to use my optocoupler in all region by changing the voltage level ultimately by changing the PWM signal from microcontroller.

Comment: The actual solution is: "I used a LOW PASS FILTER" but there's not schematic for it. Please edit your answer and show a proper schematic (*not* a photo of a hand sketched schematic). The schematic tool built into the answer editor is easy to use. I've chopped out the photos that make it long and tell nothing to new readers...

Comment: ...but you need to rewrite the text into an actual answer - something that describes what the solution is and why it works. Thanks.